# Error in installing packages of Atom Editor

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor

[Image is showing the errors while trying to install packages from Atom Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbUQQ.jpg)

I am using Windows 10 x64 and Atom version 1.49.0

Answer (score 0):

It could be a server problem. Have you tried

```
apm install <package-name>
```

?
(This will only work if `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\atom\bin` is in your `PATH` file)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes, I have tried this and it worked from cmd. But my question is why is it not working from Atom Editor!